# Finding the result of $1/2*1/3...*1/1000$

Tags: group-theory, binary-operations

Let the binary operation $x*y=(x+y)/(1+xy)$ where $x,y\in (-1,1)$
Find $(1/2)*(1/3)*...*(1/1000)$

I found that $1/x*1/y=(x+y)/(1+xy)$ but I can not find a rule for $n$ such numbers and apply induction to calculate that sum.

Could you please tell me what would be another way to solve the problem?

Comment: Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and enhance your question

Comment: Well, truncating the product at $n$ for the first few $n$ should at least give you a very good idea of what the answer is, at least in the limit.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: To solve this problem, compute the product $(x_0)(x_1)...(x_n)$ of finitely many terms using your binary operation. Find the pattern, and prove what you see; It is a pretty symmetric result. After this, computing the final value should not be too hard. If you want a complete answer, then ask for one in the comments after you have tried it yourself.